# Какую технологию использовать для рисования на сайте?

Tags: jquery, svg, canvas

Подскажите, какую технологию можно использовать для рисования и получения данных? Вроде как canvas, но не уверен.
Человек заходит на страницу сайта, вводит ширину и высоту прямоугольника, этот прямоугольник делиться на равные прямоугольники(по высоте), далее, кривыми, может Бизье, он делает, например волну по низу, в итоге мы получаем что-то типа ламбрикена, и так как высота каждого прямоугольника разная, нужно получить именно высоту этих прямоугольников. Как-то так.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. "Как-то так."

Comment: Что именно @Igor?

Comment: Как я могу сказать, что именно мне непонятно, если мне непонятно, что Вам нужно, и в чем трудность?

Comment: Трудность в том, что не знаю какую технологию использовать для подобного варианта.

Comment: и svg и canvas отлично подойдут, svg - проще

Answer (score 6):

Собрал что то по мотивам вопроса на `d3.js`, из кода моих прошлых примеров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var points = [[300,20],[200,40],[100,20],[50,50],[80,80],[50,110],[70,140]];

let dragged = null, 
    selected = points[points.length-1];

let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);
let svg = d3.select("svg");

let leftRect = svg.select("rect.left").on("mousedown", mousedown);
let rightRect = svg.select("rect.right");
let leftPath = svg.select("path.left").datum(points);
let rightPath = svg.select("path.right").datum(points);

resize();

d3.select(window)
    .on("mousemove", e => {
      if (!dragged) 
          return;
      let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
      dragged[0] = m[0];
      dragged[1] = m[1];
      redraw();
    })
    .on("mouseup", e => dragged = null);

function resize() {
  svg.attr("width", +width.value)
     .attr("height", +height.value);
      
  leftRect.attr("width", +width.value/2)
          .attr("height", +height.value)
          
  rightRect.attr("x", +width.value/2)
           .attr("width", +width.value/2)
           .attr("height", +height.value);
           
  rightPath.attr("transform", `scale(-1,1) translate(-${+width.value},0)`)
  redraw();
}

function redraw() {

  svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", line);  
  
  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(points, d => d);
  
  circles.exit().remove();
    
  let newNodes = circles.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 6.5)
      .on("mousedown", d => { 
          selected = dragged = d; 
          redraw(); 
      });

  circles.merge(newNodes)
      .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
      .attr("cx", d => d[0])
      .attr("cy", d => d[1]);
}

function mousedown() {
  selected = dragged = d3.mouse(svg.node())
  points.push(selected);
  redraw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui" onkeyup="resize()">
  <input value=600 id="width">
  <input value=150 id="height">
</div>
<svg>
  <rect class="left"></rect>
  <rect class="right"></rect>
  <path class="left"></path>
  <path class="right"></path>
</svg>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  rect.left {
    fill: #eee;
  }

  rect.right {
    fill: wheat;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  circle, path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  circle {
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .2;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .selected {
    fill: #ff7f0e;
    stroke: #ff7f0e;
  }

  .ui {
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow:  0 1px 1px 0 lightgray;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Если изменить размер, то нарисованное остаётся на своём же месте - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/dDg4def.png?1)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я вкурсе, и удаления точек нет, но это за рамками данного вопроса, не хочу усложнять сниппет

Comment: Верю, просто "порисовать" хотел, а тут такое :D

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 ну сдвиг оси  симметрии я поправил =)

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @spoon100500 спрашивайте по коду если что-то не понятно

Comment: А что-то подобное как сдесь https://youtu.be/rmnuW9GoX_M можно сделать на jquery?

Comment: можно на d3 можно на jquery, можно на голом js - потребуются знания svg

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, подскажите, добавляю событие "mousedown" для изменения 'height' в rect, высота меняется но только на убавление, понятно, что событие пропадает из this при изменении высоты, как можно сделать изменение высоты при нажатии в обе стороны? https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/3gnvuqhp/

Comment: @spoon100500 предлагаю подложить под зеленые прямоугильники еще белые, по колотым слушать клик

Comment: Ну как вариант, да можно. А как написать именно вам сообщение тут?)))
А если назначить на сам блог svg событие, а присваивать через this ректу?